# Immediate function invocation in jQuery library

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does this JavaScript/JQuery Syntax work: (function( window, undefined ) { })(window)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716069/how-does-this-javascript-jquery-syntax-work-function-window-undefined)

I am trying to breakdown some of the parts of jQuery to better understand what's going on behind the scenes.  For the most part, I am pretty clear on a lot of it's methods, but the first line of code looks like this:

```
(function( window, undefined ) {
```

and the library ends like this

```
})( window );
```

I understand that this is immediate function invocation, but what does this do in context to the jQuery library?  I'm not sure what I am looking at.

Also, where else would this be useful to us?

Comment: Basically it's a way of avoiding polluting the global scope: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265823/javascript-global-scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is passing the current window object into jQuery so it has a reference to the window as a local object.

It is also not passing in a second parameter so that undefined will truly be "undefined". The reason to do this is that it would be possible to assign undefined a value, so by expecting a value as a second parameter, but not getting one, jQuery is assuring itself that it really has undefined.

Comment: Gotcha, makes sense.  Thanks for clearing this up.